I cannot extract .sql CREATE TABLEs for each table in my Azure SQL Database in my Azure Repo
Like the question says, how can I do that? This is the script I am currently using through the generation of a .dacpac file, but I've seen that this can be done with a PowerShell script instead of AzureCLI@2?
I tried this AzureCLI@2 script:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      set -e
      echo "Starting DACPAC extraction..."     
      # Obtain an access token
      echo "Obtaining access token..."
      accessToken=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net/ --query accessToken --output tsv)
      echo "Access token obtained."
      # Check if the access token was retrieved
      if [ -z "$accessToken" ]; then
        echo "Failed to obtain access token. Exiting."
        exit 1
      fi
      # Create directories if they don't exist
      mkdir -p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC
      mkdir -p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/some/ran/dir/
      # Extract DACPAC file to a temporary directory
      echo "Extracting DACPAC file..."
      ./sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:$(sqlServerName) /SourceDatabaseName:$(sqlDatabaseName) /TargetFile:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac /AccessToken:$accessToken
      # Unzip the extracted DACPAC file
      echo "Unzipping DACPAC file..."
      unzip -o $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac -d $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC     
      # Move extracted schema files to the target directory, replacing existing files
      echo "Replacing existing .sql files with updated schema..."
      find $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC -name '*.sql' -exec cp -v {} $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/some/ran/dir/ \; 2>error.log      
      echo "Schema extraction and replacement completed."
      echo "Listing files in target directory..."
      ls -l $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/some/ran/dir/  
      ls -l $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC
      # Commit and push the changes
      echo "Committing and pushing changes..."
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      git config --global user.email "$(sqlAdminLogin)"
      git config --global user.name "Name"
      git add --all
      git status
      git commit -m "Update schema files from DACPAC extraction" || echo "No changes to commit"
      git push https://$(azureDevOpsPat)@dev.azure.com/my/git/repo/here HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranch) --force
      ls -l $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/some/ran/dir/
      echo "Changes committed and pushed."

I was expecting it to commit the files to the designated location, but it just says detached head. Trying to change the repo branch through using checkout and creating a temporary branch doesn't work either.
Update #1
This is what my pipeline shows for the above-mentioned task:
HEAD detached at fc510bf
nothing to commit, working tree clean
HEAD detached at fc510bf
nothing to commit, working tree clean
No changes to commit
Everything up-to-date

It does, however, show each script in the following dir:
-rw-r--r-- 1 vsts docker  995 Jul 24 06:42 Surgeons.sql

Update #2
The following path works, but I added it to my .gitignore as I am looking to have only the .sql scripts for each table:
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC

Update #3
The script pulls this script:
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact Report](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Report Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Report Description] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Customer ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Follow Up] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Feedback] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [text] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact Report] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

But it should pull this script (As used in Azure Data Factory):
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact Report](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Report Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Report Description] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Customer ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Follow Up] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Feedback] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Staff ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact Report] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact Report]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactReport_Staff] FOREIGN KEY([Staff ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Staff] ([Staff ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact Report] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactReport_Staff]
GO

-Update #4
   echo "Extracting DACPAC file..."
   ./sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:$(sqlServerName) /SourceDatabaseName:$(sqlDatabaseName) /TargetFile:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac /AccessToken:$accessToken
   # Unzip the extracted DACPAC file
   echo "Unzipping DACPAC file..."
   unzip -o $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac -d $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC     
   # Move extracted schema files to the target directory, replacing existing files
   echo "Replacing existing .sql files with updated schema..."
   find $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC -name '*.sql' -exec cp -v {} $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Database/dbo/Tables/ \; 2>error.log 


What issues did you encounter when running the script? Can you share more details?

This is the response I receive in the pipeline (The test does pass, however)
'HEAD detached at fc510bf
nothing to commit, working tree clean
No changes to commit
Everything up-to-date
Changes committed and pushed.'
All the scripts display correctly in the list using:
ls -l $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/some/ran/repo/

After running the pipeline, can you see the expected files in the repo? If possible, you can update the question to share the pipeline logs.

From the updated log, the message: No changes to commit Everything up-to-date This means that the files are not updated when doing the git push action. Can you confirm if the .sql files have changed in each pipeline run? If the sql file not change, it can not commit any changes to the repo.

The scripts it pulls are from the current schema within the database which is different to what is currently in the repo, so there are changes that can be made.

Can you add the cat $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/some/ran/dir/sqlfilename.sql in the bash script to output the content? And then you can double confirm if the file content are different from the file in repo.

Is it still considered best practice if I store the .dacpac file in my Repo and remove the Database SQL Scripts for all the tables?

As far as I know, the dacpac file and ,sql file can be used to store tables. It depends on your preference. But the current issue should not be related to this point. It is more related to the git itself. We need to make sure that the files have changed in the repo. Then we can do the commit and push action.

I shall respond with a further update above.

From the latest update, do you mean that the script pulls the wrong sql script file?

The .sql file the script pulls is what is stored in my repo, which is the older version. The script is not pulling the updated .sql file from the sql Database.

May I know if the two sql files have the same name(pull from script and sql file in the repo)? If yes, can you copy the updated sql file to a new folder and check if it can show the expected script?

On the other hand, you also need to check if the sqlpackage command is Extracting the correct database.

I tried that and have spent the last while trying to sort out the issue. It wouldn't push any changes to the repo, even after adding a new folder. It said there were no changes detected. Still received the detached heard error. Tried using git checkout $(Build.SourceBranch), but to no avail.
It is extracting the correct database. The variables are correctly defined and work perfectly in all other use cases.

The detached heard output is not an error. This is an expected behavior when running git status. Only adding a new folder without any files, it still shows the nothing to commit output. You need to add a new file to the new folder. Then it will show the updated commit. On the other hand, you can try to remove the .gitignore file and check if it can work.

The .gitignore does not ignore any .sql files. I am trying to add the extracted .sql files from the database to the new folder, but nothing still. I added a file to the new folder and still nothing. It adds the new file and folder, but it does not add the extracted sql scripts to the folder. I have added an update of the lines that deal with the dacpac.

Do you mean that only the .sql file will be ignored when doing the git push and other files can be push to the repo?

So, all files are pushed to the repo, except for the files extracted from the .dacpac.

Can you confirm if the sql files contains in the dacpac package? Based on my test, when I unzip the .dacpac file, it only contains the XML files.

Please try to add the argument: /p:ExtractTarget=File in the sqlpackage command. For example:  ./sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:$(sqlServerName) /SourceDatabaseName:$(sqlDatabaseName) /TargetFile:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac /AccessToken:$accessToken /p:ExtractTarget=File In this case, the dacpac file will contain a sql file.

From the Bash script you shared, the cause of the issue could be that the following command will only extract single .dacpac file. There is no .sql files in the output.
./sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:$(sqlServerName) /SourceDatabaseName:$(sqlDatabaseName) /TargetFile:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac /AccessToken:$accessToken

To solve this issue, we need to add the argument: /p:ExtractTarget=File in the sqlpackage command. If you don't define the ExtractTarget argument, it will be set to DacPac by default.
For example:
./sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:$(sqlServerName) /SourceDatabaseName:$(sqlDatabaseName) /TargetFile:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/temp/DACPAC/$(sqlDatabaseName).dacpac /AccessToken:$accessToken /p:ExtractTarget=File

In this case, it will output a .dacpac single file and one or more .sql files.
Then you can copy the .sql files to the target folder to push to Azure Repo.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: SqlPackage Extract parameters and properties
